# Append with id of each element

Tags: jquery, append

I have a variable `name` of which gives me few elements:

```
console.log(name) = joe,foo,john,maria
```

and the variable `src` gives me a link of each of the names:

`console.log(src) = www.joe.com, www.foo.com, www.john.com and www.maria.com` respectively.

Now I want to append a div of which each will have the id of the 'name' and for text the link for each so I will end up with something likes this:

```
<div id="joe">www.joe.com</div>
<div id="foo">www.foo.com</div>
<div id="john">www.john.com</div>
<div id="maria">www.maria.com</div>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var arr = [];
var textToInsert = '';
$.each(arr, function(count, item) {
  textToInsert  += '<div id="'+ name +'">' + a + '</div>';
});

$('body').append(textToInsert);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming name and src are arrays of strings, you're just about there--get the index of the name item from name and use it to grab the corresponding src url in the other array.  Otherwise, make a map out of the two lists and do it that way.

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var arr2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4];
var result = "";

$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    result += '<div id="' + value + '">' + arr2[index] + "</div>"

});

$('body').html(result);
```

Comment: Can you please check my fiddle because ur answer doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/Hq8fD/

Comment: I ran mine in jsfiddle before I posted it.

Comment: The jsfiddle example in your link is not related to the one in your question.  But one thing I notice is that you are using non-standard attributes in your input tags to store the url.  If you must store data on the page like that, use a hidden div or input instead.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but this should work.

```
var names = name.split(',');
var srcs = src.split(',');
var textToInsert = '';
var currentName;
var currentSrc;
for (index in names) {
  var currentName = names[index];
  var currentSrc = srcs[index];
  textToInsert  += '<div id="'+ name +'">' + a + '</div>';
}

$('body').append(textToInsert);
```

Comment: Can you please check my fiddle because ur answer doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/Hq8fD/

Answer (score 1):

Quick example here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name = ['joe','foo','john','maria'];
    var src = ['www.joe.com', 'www.foo.com', 'www.john.com','www.maria.com']
    var html = "";           
    for(i=0;i<name.length;i++){
         html += "<div id='" + name[i] + "'>" + src[i] + "</div>" 
    }

     $("body").append(html);
 });​
```

Comment: Can you please check my fiddle because ur answer doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/Hq8fD/

Comment: your question and the jsfiddle you have posted does not have any relation.

Comment: I ran mine in jsfiddle before I posted it.

Comment: @BenBrunk my comment was a reply to jquerybeast.

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't test this but this is how I interpreted your question ...

```
var name = ['joe','foo','john','maria'];
var src = ['www.joe.com','www.foo.com','www.john.com','www.maria.com'];
var str = "";
for (var i=0;j=name.length;i<j;i++) {
    str += "<div id='" + name[i] + "'>" + src[i] + "</a>\n";
}
document.write(str);
```

Comment: Can you please check my fiddle because ur answer doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/Hq8fD/

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqub4/7/)

```
var arr = ['joe', 'foo', 'john', 'maria'];
$.each(arr, function(count, item) {
    var a = 'www.' + item + '.com';
    $('body').append('<div id="' + item + '"><a href="http://' + a + '">' + a + '</a></div>');
});
```